# Private Set Methods in Python. Oxymoron?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Generally get and set methods are for the user to access.

However, I have an attribute I need to update in my class within a public method. This update is one with a private method in the same class.

I'm more curious on the naming convention protocol for this.

Namely, should a private set method look like this?

```
def _set_player_turn(self):
    pass
```

Or is the idea of a private set method an oxymoron?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be writing getters and setters. What does your setter actually do?

Comment: This is for a class project. In this example, whenever a player makes a move, this method is run and it changes the "player_turn" variable to the next player.

Comment: Yeah again, you generally don't write getters and setters in python if they are like really *just getting and setting*. You would use just a normal attribute, and then, if you need to modify how access occurs later you can use a `property`. But obviously, you should just follow the instructions of your professor. They are teaching you general principles not necessarily Python per se

Comment: You clearly come from [another language]. There is no concept of `private methods` in Python. More importantly, don't write getters and setters, use `@property` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an oxymoron. Just because your class does not expose a way to set an attribute doesn't mean it cannot provide a "private" method for its own, internal use.

Comment: So a leading underscore before a set method is an ok approach?

Comment: Yes, the leading underscore just means "this is not part of the public interface". It says nothing about what the method *does*.

Comment: I've gotten some mixed messaging on this other piece. For private variables is the convention a single leading underscore and for private methods two leading underscores?

Comment: No, the two leading underscores is really a step beyond private-vs-public; they induce name mangling so that a child class cannot accidentally interfere with a parent class attribute of the same name. The closest analogy would be to treat `_name` as *protected* and `__name` as private, but as *everything* in Python is public (even `__name`, if you use the mangled name `__foo_name`, where `foo` is the appropriate class name), the analogy only goes so far.

Comment: @chepner I've always thought saying a single-undercore is "protected" is implying much more granularity than it should. A single underscore should be treated as private. Protected is way too permissive anyway, if we are going by the Java example

Comment: That's why I have "private" in quotes; I don't really like trying to pigeonhole the convention into another language's visibility model. It's simply a recommendation to not use the attribute (whether variable or method) outside of the class itself.